# Is it possible to change the color of Wicket's activity indicator?

Tags: java, colors, wicket, background-color, activity-indicator

Situation: I'm working with Wicket's `IndicatingAjaxButton`. I have the button set up on a page with black background. When the user pushes the button, the button's activity indicator goes off and spins until the system is ready to move on.

Problem: Because of the black background, the indicator looks bad. Since part of the indicator is animated in black, some of the details are lost using the indicator on a black background.

Question: Is it possible in Wicket to change the color of the `IndicatingX` [Button, Link, etc.], or do I have to design my page in a new way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Well, not programmatically.

Wicket's activity indicator/throbber/spinner is actually nothing more than an animated GIF. It's located at

> `[your version of Wicket here]\wicket-src\wicket\src\main\java\org\apache\wicket\ajax\indicator.gif`

and [referenced in `AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior`](http://jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/wicket/wicket/1.4.15/wicket-1.4.15-sources.jar!/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java?format=ok).

To change the colors, you could create your own animated GIF of the same size and overwrite the one that's included in the default distribution.

EDIT:
Okay, after writing that I thought "there must be free icons available" and came up with this through Google Image Search:

http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/gduthie/WindowsLiveWriter/Needananimatedloadingicon_B811/ajax-loader_2.gif

I *think* it's free and unrestricted to use, but I didn't check too carefully. You should check for yourself if you're using it for anything more than a personal toy/sample app.

Answer (score 4):

So piggybacking off what Lord Torgamus provided, you could add a class like this:

```
abstract class OnBlackIndicatingAjaxButton extends AjaxButton implements
  IAjaxIndicatorAware {
    private final AjaxIndicatorAppender indicatorAppender = new
      AjaxIndicatorAppender() {
        @Override
        protected CharSequence getIndicatorUrl() {
            return "http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/gduthie/WindowsLiveWriter/Needananimatedloadingicon_B811/ajax-loader_2.gif";
        }
    };

    public OnBlackIndicatingAjaxButton(String id) {
        super(id);
        add (indicatorAppender);
    }

    public OnBlackIndicatingAjaxButton(String id, Form<?> form)
    {
        super(id, form);
        add (indicatorAppender);
    }

    /**
     * @see IAjaxIndicatorAware#getAjaxIndicatorMarkupId()
     * @return the markup id of the ajax indicator
     * 
     */
    public String getAjaxIndicatorMarkupId()
    {
        return indicatorAppender.getMarkupId();
    }
}
```

and use that for any of your pages.