# Wicket loading icon/popup while performing logic

Tags: java, javascript, popup, load, wicket

In my **Wicket application** I have a few lines of code that take some time to execute. It would be nice, if I could show a loading icon or popup, during the time the logic is being excecuted. The problem is that I have no idea how to implement something like this. Can someone help me with this?

And the **Goal** is

```
Class.java
    // Show popup or icon
    this.getData();
    // Hide popup
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this wicket wiki:

[Generic Busy Indicator (for both Ajax and non-Ajax submits)](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/generic-busy-indicator-for-both-ajax-and-non-ajax-submits.html)

If you are using ajax button/link you can use `IndicatingAjaxLink` and `IndicatingAjaxButton` both comes from wicket-extensions

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
<artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
<version>${wicket.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Links about custom indicators:

[Customizing IndicatingAjaxLink in wicket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773885/customizing-indicatingajaxlink-in-wicket)

[Is it possible to change the color of Wicket's activity indicator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665729/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-wickets-activity-indicator)

And you can also override the css class:

```
span.wicket-ajax-indicator img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 2px;
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thx! The IndicatingAjaxLink is working. A loading icon is shown. The only problem left is the location of the icon. I would like to show the loading icon on the button itself, or in the center of the screen. How is the location specified?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [AjaxLazyLoadPanel](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/AjaxLazyLoadPanel.html). Put the display of the stuff that takes long into an Panel and wrap it with AjaxLazyLoadPanel.

Comment: Is something like this also possible for a button? In my application, I have a panel with a button, and the buttons performs an action that takes a few seconds (onEvent action).

Comment: Than I think the above answer by Rangel is better suited.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a pop up that you would want to customize, then you can use a [modal](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/modal-window;jsessionid=BF03586306102A3D86F318515E99DAE5?0)

window. Follow the tutorial to load a modal window on click.

Have whatever text you please on the destination panel.

In onConfigure() of modalPanel1 (destination panel), in the end add the following code:

```
Thread.sleep(//time average);
window.close(target);
```

Where target is passed as a parameter to the constructor from the ModalWindowPage.java as an object for the constructor.

So ideally this is the change in instantiating:

```
modal2.setContent(new ModalPanel1(modal2.getContentId(),target);
```

where target is the ajax link/button target.

You can also activate it on the load of page (Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063002/how-open-modal-window-on-page-load-in-wicket-1-5) to view the discussion)